# How do I use bold and underline when entering events on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

Can I bold and underline events entered in my Google calendar?  The bar above would be nice.

Comment: what did you try? did you search Google?

Comment: In what setting are you asking? The mobile app? The website? Do you mean just in the calendar view? Can you provide an image of what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can only use plain text in Calendar titles, locations, and descriptions.

If you want text formatting, you'll need to use a different service.